# How to configure AspNetCore Identity and Auth0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, auth0

I created a sample project within VS 2017 using ASP.NET Core Templates 1.1 (Web Application) changing the authentication to be Individual User Accounts.

From there I followed the instructions at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/

and

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core/01-login

The Startup.cs is essentially

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(
            options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });

        services.AddMvc(options=>
        {
            options.SslPort = 44321;
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<Auth0Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("Auth0"));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<Auth0Settings> auth0Settings)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });

        var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions("Auth0")
        {
            Authority = $"https://{auth0Settings.Value.Domain}",

            ClientId = auth0Settings.Value.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = auth0Settings.Value.ClientSecret,

            AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            AutomaticChallenge = false,
            SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,

            ResponseType = "code",

            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-auth0"),

            // Configure the Claims Issuer to be Auth0
            ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0",

        };
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I register a user, navigate to manage your account and click, Manage link next to External Logins.

I click Auth0 button and successfully login. I get redirected to /Manage/LinkLoginCallback where the following method returns null.

```
private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
{
    return _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
}
```

Causing the following to appear

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request. Development
>   Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed
>   information about the error that occurred.
>
> Development environment should not be enabled in deployed
>   applications, as it can result in sensitive information from
>   exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging,
>   development environment can be enabled by setting the
>   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and
>   restarting the application.

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong with respect to configuring Auth0 and Identity. In addition, if you know how to address the error above when the launchSettings.json does have ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as Development, that would also be much appreciated.

Comment: I came across this warning when I commented out "app.UseCookieAuthentication();". Just a stab in the dark, Maybe you could try UseCookieAuthentication without the CookieAuthenticationOptions parameter?